# CSS Flexbox: How to make the children elements occupy the entire width of their container

Tags: css, flexbox

Please look at my code here: http://codepen.io/CrazySynthax/pen/NdJbmB

```
<table>
    <div id="table-header">
    <div class=header-square>SUN</div>
    <div class=header-square>MON</div>
    <div class=header-square>TUE</div>
    <div class=header-square>WED</div>
    <div class=header-square>THU</div>
    <div class=header-square>FRI</div>
    <div class=header-square>SAT</div>
  </div>

</table>

html, body {
    width: 100%
}

#table-header {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header-square {
    background-color: aqua;
    border: solid;
    height:100px;
    display:flex;
}
```

I want that the elements of class header-square will be spread on the entire width of the container, meaning that the total width of header-squares will be 100% of the page.

How can I do it without explicitly defining a width for header-square class in css?

Answer (score 3):

Just apply `flex: 1` to your `.header-square` elements to occupy entire width.

```
.header-square {
    background-color: aqua;
    border: solid;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
```

**EDIT**

To occupy entire height, add the following:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#table-header {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And remove fixed `height: 100px` from `.header-square`.

Result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. and if I want to do the same regarding the height?

Comment: @CrazySynthax Check *EDIT*

Comment: Can you please explain what "flex:1" does generally?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex1-mean Alternatively you can head over to the W3C article regarding the same: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common

Answer (score 1):

Add `flex: 1` to class '.header-square'

Comment: I gave this answer at the same time.I didn't know that someone is about to give the same answer. Sorry I don't have sixth sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-square {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(100% / 7);
}
```

The `.header-square` is missing `width` attribute. Therefore you should expand to 100% by doing `width: calc(100% / 7);` to achieve your desired result.