# react-select does not display with column-count

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a bunch of react-select components on the screen. They are all inside a div with a class called bookData. The css for bookData is:

```
.bookData{
  font-size:13px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

If I select something with react-select, the selection does not show up. If I remove column-count, my code for react-select works find, it will select items and display. Is there css, I can add that will allow react-select to work with column-count?

Comment: You can use `display:flex` and fit content as you want.

Comment: why does column-count break this component though?

Comment: display: flex does not give the ability to wrap columns properly. column-count does the exact functionality I need. Two columns equal in length, wrapping in the middle. Flex forces me to hard code a break, and puts items in a grid format.

Answer (score 1):

This CodeSandbox could help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/4jr596lr09

All you need to do is to wrap the two column content in a div displayed by flex.
Wrap the two elements in a div and set the flex value to 1 (Ref: [What does flex: 1 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37386244/4752488))

Comment: That is close. But with this method, I have to place half of my divs in one column and half of my divs in the other column to get them to align correctly. This partially solves the problem. I can also set up flex to have columns, but then I need a height to get it to wrap. It does not seem like there is a solution that mimics column-count where I want to have 2 columns and let the content flow evenly between the two columns.

Comment: I think I am learning why they introduced column-count. It does something flexbox cannot solve.

Comment: Give me an example of your divs and column structure to help you.

Comment: I have array data lists that users can add and remove items from. So if one list gets really large, that column will be far larger than the second column. column-count fixes this because it says fit all of the divs inside a single div to be as close to even to two columns as possible. Flexbox says take the items in these two divs and give them a basis and grow and shrink. Or you can tell flex to have columns, give it a height and it will wrap whenever it reaches that height.

Comment: really would prefer for the react-select people to fix their component so it works with column-count. But that may be a pipe dream based on other comments I have seen on their github.

Comment: Ok, you can open an issue to their repo. But they have 1013 issues opened. I recommend you to use a different solution or component.

Comment: thanks for your help in better understanding basis grow and shrink.