# flex: n with different n of items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating a circles and lines component and I'm trying to understand a lil better how flex box does its magic. Specifically, flex: n.

Visually, the three versions have the same amount of items in them, the first one looks normal? whereas the other two don't scale.

What's breaking it?

How to fix this?

```css
      .chart {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 15px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
      }
      .dot-black {
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: black;
      }

      .dot-grey {
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        background: grey;
      }

      .dot-green {
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        background: green;
      }

      .line-black {
       height: 2px;
       background: black;
       flex: 1;
      }

      .line-grey {
       height: 2px;
       background: grey;
       flex: 1;
      }

      .gradient {
      display: flex;
      opacity: 0.2;
      flex: 6;
      align-items: center;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="chart">
      <div class="gradient" style="flex: 1">
        <span class="dot-black"></span>      
        <span class="line-black"></span>   
        <span class="dot-grey"></span> 
      </div>  
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>    
    </div>

    <div class="chart">
      <div class="gradient" style="flex: 1">
        <span class="dot-black"></span>      
        <span class="line-black"></span>   
        <span class="dot-grey"></span> 
        <span class="line-grey"></span>
        <span class="dot-grey"></span>  
      </div>       
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>    
    </div>

    <div class="chart">
      <div class="gradient" style="flex: 2">
        <span class="dot-black"></span>      
        <span class="line-black"></span>   
        <span class="dot-grey"></span> 
        <span class="line-grey"></span>
        <span class="dot-grey"></span>  
      </div>       
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>          
      <span class="line-grey"></span>
      <span class="dot-grey"></span>    
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/37386244/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex: 1 means that each element takes up an equal division of available space in the flexbox.  You have different numbers of elements inside the container with the `gradient` class, which has `flex: 1` and is treated as only a single child element of the `chart` flexbox.  That means on the 2nd example you're compressing two sets of lines/dots into the space meant for one, but the overall size of each flex unit is larger because there are fewer children.

The slight discrepancy on the 3rd is caused by the dot elements being statically sized. Having a `flex: 1` line and a static dot takes up `flex: 1` width + the dot width.  Putting a line and a dot inside a `flex: 1` container means it only takes up the amount of space allotted by even division.  You'll notice in the first example the first segment is slightly smaller for this reason.

One solution is to group everything you want to be evenly sized in containers you apply flex: 1 to, and control the opacity/styles with another class.

I made an example [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/YbygBL).

Comment: but what if I want the gradient to be consistent in terms of covering more than one group, rather than multiple separate gradients back to back?