# My wrapper and books container are not aligned, how do i go about fixing this using flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Basically its just a bit off by a few px. I did margin right and padding right and it works, but pages would be to far off. I either want it aligning with the Wrapper or just in the middle of it.

```
div class="bookContainer">
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>Title</h2>
<h2>Author</h2>
<h2>Pages</h2>
<h2>Read</h2>
</div>
<div class="books"> 
    <p>The Hobbit</p>
    <p>by J.R.R. Tolkien</p>
    <p>295 pages</p>
    <p>Read</p>
</div>
</div>

.bookContainer{
width: 90%;
border:2px solid black;
margin: auto;
}
.books {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;

}
.wrapper {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of making this work is to add `flex:1` and `text-align:center` to each of the flexbox items.

```css
.bookContainer{
width: 90%;
border:2px solid black;
margin: auto;
}
.books {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;

}
.wrapper {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}
.item {
flex:1;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookContainer">
<div class="wrapper">
<h2 class="item">Title</h2>
<h2 class="item">Author</h2>
<h2 class="item">Pages</h2>
<h2 class="item">Read</h2>
</div>
<div class="books"> 
    <p class="item">The Hobbit</p>
    <p class="item">by J.R.R. Tolkien</p>
    <p class="item">295 pages</p>
    <p class="item">Read</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! Stupid question ,but why does this work.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean#answer-37386828), `flex` is shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. Just typing in `flex 1` is equivalent to typing `flex: 1 1 0`, which makes each flexbox item equal width. The [answer below that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean#answer-37386525) explains what all of the "flex" properties do individually.