# CSS HTML - Large white gap between body and footer

Tags: html, css

[My Webpage Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyEbM.png)

I don't have a lot of content on this index page, so there's a large white gap between my content and my footer. Pls look at the image.

How do I color this white space orange? Or extend my "white" page until it reaches the footer.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page {
  background-color: #ffd000;
  position: relative;
}

.top-menu-container {
  color: #ffd000;
  background-color: #ff6500;
  padding: 20px 0;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top-menu {
  border: 3px solid #ffd000;
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.top-links {
  border: 2px solid #005aff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.top-links a {
  color: #ffd000;
}

.top-links a:hover {
  color: #005aff;
  font-style: underline;
}

.top-title p {
  color: red;
}

.login {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.horizontal-grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.horizontal-box {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.horizontal-box-item {
  background-color: #005aff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Ariel;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffa500;
}

.horizontal-box-item a {
  color: #ffd000;
}

.horizontal-box-item a:hover {
  color: #000;
  font-style: underline;
}

.first-item {
  order: 0;
}

.second-item {
  order: 1;
}

.page-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page-box {
  width: 900px;
  border: 3px solid #ff6500;
  font-family: Ariel;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.page-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffa500;
}

.page-text ul li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  background: #ffd000;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.footer p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>
  <div class='top-menu-container'>
    <div class='top-menu'>
      <div class='top-title'>Action &amp; Improve</div>
      <div class='top-links'>
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='horizontal-grid-container'>
    <div class='horizontal-box'>
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='page-container'>
    <div class='page-box'>
      <div class='page-text'>
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Copyright blah 2020</p>
</div>
```

I've tried playing about with Flexbox and just adding in Background-color: at various places but no luck.

I'm using Django and Python for the backend of this website so I've removed  the python code from the webpage.

Thanks Everyone :)

Comment: no more content inbetween that why white space shown

Comment: Yes, it doesn't appear to be part of the page container either. I tried doing background-color: red; in various parts to see what would change. I guess I could just add some blank lines?

Comment: I have tested the webpage in IE Edge and it works fine, it's chrome that's producing the white space for no content!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page {
  background-color: #ffd000;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1; /* THIS NEW LINE */
}

.top-menu-container {
  color: #ffd000;
  background-color: #ff6500;
  padding: 20px 0;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top-menu {
  border: 3px solid #ffd000;
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.top-links {
  border: 2px solid #005aff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.top-links a {
  color: #ffd000;
}

.top-links a:hover {
  color: #005aff;
  font-style: underline;
}

.top-title p {
  color: red;
}

.login {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.horizontal-grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.horizontal-box {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.horizontal-box-item {
  background-color: #005aff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Ariel;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffa500;
}

.horizontal-box-item a {
  color: #ffd000;
}

.horizontal-box-item a:hover {
  color: #000;
  font-style: underline;
}

.first-item {
  order: 0;
}

.second-item {
  order: 1;
}

.page-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page-box {
  width: 900px;
  border: 3px solid #ff6500;
  font-family: Ariel;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.page-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffa500;
}

.page-text ul li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  background: #ffd000;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.footer p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>
  <div class='top-menu-container'>
    <div class='top-menu'>
      <div class='top-title'>Action &amp; Improve</div>
      <div class='top-links'>
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='horizontal-grid-container'>
    <div class='horizontal-box'>
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='page-container'>
    <div class='page-box'>
      <div class='page-text'>
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Copyright blah 2020</p>
</div>
```

Add `flex: 1` to class `.page`

At this stackoverflow asnwer the explanation: [What does flex: 1 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but it didn't work for me :(

Comment: Yes it does work, Chrome just wasn't refreshing the page. I tested it on IE and this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this Property  `flex: 1 0 auto;` fot this class `.top-menu-container`

```
.top-menu-container {
    color: #ffd000;
    background-color: #ff6500;
    padding: 20px 0;
    /*flex: 1 0 auto;*/ /*Remove this*/
    justify-content: center;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but it didn't get rid of the white space :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.
I took the HTML and CSS code out of Django and ran it as a basic webpage and CSS file. Then the above answers did sort the issue out. 
The problem must be to do with Django, maybe it doesn't refresh the CSS code quickly enough or something...

Comment: I take it back. It wasn't django. The page loads fine in IE but not in Chrome hahahaha