# Align div inside a flex to occupy whole width of the container

Tags: html, css

I have two cards which has different content. I want to stretch the width of all the cards having different content length to same width. Meaning, the width of the content should extend upto Album cover. How can i set the `width` property here so that I get the constant width in all the cards. Could anyone please help?

```css
.card {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.footer {
  float: bottom;
}

.card-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div>Music controls</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">Album Cover</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div>Adding Music controls more options</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">Album Cover</div>
</div>
```

Comment: .card-content {flex: 1}

Comment: @VXp WOW! that solved! But curious to know why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean

Comment: flex is shorthand. actually you should use flex-grow

Answer (score 0):

Add [`flex-grow: 1`](https://cssreference.io/property/flex-grow/) to `.card-content`

```css
.card {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.footer {
  float: bottom;
}

.card-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div>Music controls</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">Album Cover</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div>Adding Music controls more options</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">Album Cover</div>
</div>
```