# CSS flex-basis: 0% has different behaviour to flex-basis: 0px

Tags: css, flexbox

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), the `flex: 1` shorthand should set `flex-basis: 0`. However, it actually sets `flex-basis: 0%`, and even more surprisingly this has different behaviour.

In the example below, I expect `div.middle` to shrink and scroll because it's been given `overflow-y: auto` and `flex: 1`, which should also imply `flex-basis: 0`. But it doesn't - the entire body scrolls instead because it refuses to shrink. If you uncomment the explicit `flex-basis: 0`, it then works correctly.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.outer {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #99f;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.middle {
  background: #f99;
  flex: 1;
  /*flex-basis: 0;*/
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='top'>top</div>
  <div class='middle'>
    A
    <div style='height:800px'></div>
    B
  </div>
  <div class='bottom'>bottom</div>
</div>
```

I tested this in both Chrome 84.0 and Firefox 68.11.0esr and they both have the same unexpected behaviour.

1. Why does `flex-basis: 0%` differ from `flex-basis: 0`?
2. Why does `flex: 1` set `flex-basis: 0%` instead of `flex-basis: 0`?

Comment: Great catch! This non-expect-complaint behavior is still present in firefox 90 and chrome 91.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is related to the usage of percentage. Using `0` or `0px` is trivial since you will set the initial height to be `0` and then the element will grow to fill the remaining space.

Using `N%` is a different story because in this case you are setting the initial height to be based on the parent height.

> Percentages:   relative to the flex container’s inner main size <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property)</sup>

In your case, the flex container doesn't have any explicit size since your are using only a `min-height` definition so we cannot resolve the percentange value and it will fail to `auto`

If you change the min-height with height both will behave the same:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.outer {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #99f;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.middle {
  background: #f99;
  flex: 1;
  /*flex-basis: 0;*/
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='top'>top</div>
  <div class='middle'>
    A
    <div style='height:800px'></div>
    B
  </div>
  <div class='bottom'>bottom</div>
</div>
```

> Why does flex: 1 set flex-basis: 0% instead of flex-basis: 0?

Check this: [What does flex: 1 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37386244/8620333)
Not all the browser are setting `flex:1` to be equal to `flex:1 1 0`

Comment: The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) clearly states "When omitted from the flex shorthand, its specified value is '0'". Why are browsers violating the spec and setting 0% instead?

Comment: @SystemParadox because following the Spec is never an obligation. Some browser decide to do things differently either intentionally or by mistake (which we call a *bug*)

Comment: Further proof that @TemaniAfif is indeed right: if we change `min-height: 100%;` to `height: 100%;`, things work as expected (i.e., `flex-basis: 0%` behaves like `flex-basis: 0`)

Comment: Dear Sir, you are a genius. That's all 

Comment: @TemaniAfif i'm late to the party, but: may you point me to the place where the fallback to `auto` is specified, please?