# overflow: scroll on div with flex: 1 without specific height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout kinda like Discord.
My list is the messageList with all messages I have.
I want to add overflow-y: scroll to it but it doesn't work because I don't have a specific height.
Also, I don't want to add a specific height because it should be dynamic.

My solution would be.

max-height: calc(100vh - header.height - send.height)

but it only works if you have specific heights for header and send tho.

is there any other way?

example: https://jsfiddle.net/AvaPLaIN/b7umpgzn/44/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-height: 3rem;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.chatbox {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.members {
  width: 15rem;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.list {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.send {
  height: 5rem;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header here
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="chatbox">
      <ul class="list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="send">
        Send Message here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="members">
      Memberlist here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give height in percentages instead, Which will keep it responsive and also help you fix your scroll issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `flex: 1 1 0` instead of `flex: 1` in `.list`.

The problem is related to `flex-basis` property and `flex: 1` shorthand.

`flex-basis: 0px` and `flex-basis: 0%` have different results in some cases. Here is an answer to explain the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63475286/15924950

Also, I made a simple demo to show how difference between `flex-basis: 0px` and `flex-basis: 0%`: https://codepen.io/shadow-mike/pen/NWpNVvv

Comment: thanks :) exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is a solid layout for dynamic scrolling section using mostly flexbox and grid.  Run 'full page' in snippet.  Obviously you would need media queries to adjust for mobile.

```css
 body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;

    }

    header {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 50px;
      color: #fff;
      background: #40B6C0;

    }

    .column-1 {
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      flex-direction: column;
      grid-gap: 0;
      width: 30%;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-direction: column;

    }

    .column-1 div {
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
    }


    .column-2 {
      background: #FF5C5C;
      width: 70%;
      display: flex;
      background: white;
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      flex-direction: column;

    }

    .column-2 ul {
      padding: 24px;
    }

    .column-2 li {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 12px 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF1;
    }

    .column-2 footer {
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0;
      background: #FF6F6F;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 24px;

    }

    #cell-1 {
      background: #2689B9;
    }

    #cell-2 {
      background: #8383C3;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />


</head>

<body>

  <header>
    This is your header
  </header>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="column-1">
      <div id="cell-1">Memberlist here</div>
      <div id="cell-2">Other Stuff Here</div>
    </div>

    <div class="column-2">
      <ul>
        <li>
          They're not aliens, they're Earth…liens!</li>
        <li>No… It's a thing; it's like a plan, but with more greatness. No… It's a thing; it's like a plan, but with
          more
          greatness. All I've got to do is pass as an ordinary human being. Simple. What could possibly go wrong?</li>

        <li>It's art! A statement on modern society, 'Oh Ain't Modern Society Awful?'!</li>
        <li>Heh-haa! Super squeaky bum time!</li>
        <li>Sorry, checking all the water in this area; there's an escaped fish.</li>
        <li>You hit me with a cricket bat.</li>
        <li>You hit me with a cricket bat. They're not aliens, they're Earth…liens! Aw, you're all Mr. Grumpy Face
          today.
          Father Christmas. Santa Claus. Or as I've always known him: Jeff.</li>

        <li>I'm the Doctor. Well, they call me the Doctor. I don't know why. I call me the Doctor too. I still don't
          know
          why.</li>
        <li>Sorry, checking all the water in this area; there's an escaped fish.</li>
        <li>I am the last of my species, and I know how that weighs on the heart so don't lie to me!</li>
        <li>You know when grown-ups tell you 'everything's going to be fine' and you think they're probably lying to
          make
          you feel better? I'm nobody's taxi service; I'm not gonna be there to catch you every time you feel like
          jumping
          out of a spaceship.</li>

        <li>Annihilate? No. No violence. I won't stand for it. Not now, not ever, do you understand me?! I'm the Doctor,
          the Oncoming Storm - and you basically meant beat them in a football match, didn't you? The way I see it,
          every
          life is a pile of good things and bad things.…hey.…the good things don't always soften the bad things; but
          vice-versa the bad things don't necessarily spoil the good things and make them unimportant.</li>

        <li>It's a fez. I wear a fez now. Fezes are cool. The way I see it, every life is a pile of good things and bad
          things.…hey.…the good things don't always soften the bad things; but vice-versa the bad things don't
          necessarily
          spoil the good things and make them unimportant.</li>

        <li>*Insistently* Bow ties are cool! Come on Amy, I'm a normal bloke, tell me what normal blokes do! They're not
          aliens, they're Earth…liens! Annihilate? No. No violence. I won't stand for it. Not now, not ever, do you
          understand me?! I'm the Doctor, the Oncoming Storm - and you basically meant beat them in a football match,
          didn't you?</li>

        <li>It's a fez. I wear a fez now. Fezes are cool. I am the last of my species, and I know how that weighs on the
          heart so don't lie to me! Heh-haa! Super squeaky bum time! No, I'll fix it. I'm good at fixing rot. Call me
          the
          Rotmeister. No, I'm the Doctor. Don't call me the Rotmeister.</li>

        <li>I'm the Doctor. Well, they call me the Doctor. I don't know why. I call me the Doctor too. I still don't
          know
          why. No, I'll fix it. I'm good at fixing rot. Call me the Rotmeister. No, I'm the Doctor. Don't call me the
          Rotmeister.</li>

        <li>Stop talking, brain thinking. Hush. *Insistently* Bow ties are cool! Come on Amy, I'm a normal bloke, tell
          me
          what normal blokes do! Annihilate? No. No violence. I won't stand for it. Not now, not ever, do you understand
          me?! I'm the Doctor, the Oncoming Storm - and you basically meant beat them in a football match, didn't you?
        </li>

        <li>You hit me with a cricket bat. Stop talking, brain thinking. Hush. Annihilate? No. No violence. I won't
          stand
          for it. Not now, not ever, do you understand me?! I'm the Doctor, the Oncoming Storm - and you basically meant
          beat them in a football match, didn't you?</li>

        <li>Saving the world with meals on wheels. Annihilate? No. No violence. I won't stand for it. Not now, not ever,
          do you understand me?! I'm the Doctor, the Oncoming Storm - and you basically meant beat them in a football
          match, didn't you?</li>

        <li>They're not aliens, they're Earth…liens! Heh-haa! Super squeaky bum time! *Insistently* Bow ties are cool!
          Come on Amy, I'm a normal bloke, tell me what normal blokes do! Stop talking, brain thinking. Hush.</li>

        <li>You know how I sometimes have really brilliant ideas? Annihilate? No. No violence. I won't stand for it. Not
          now, not ever, do you understand me?! I'm the Doctor, the Oncoming Storm - and you basically meant beat them
          in
          a football match, didn't you?</li>
      </ul>

      <footer>type your message here</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```