# How can I place View and icon as I want when i use flexDirection:"row"?

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOe2m.png)

Its clearly seen in the photo that texts which are "8 Tasks" and "Event" dont start from the same line, and "+" icons dont finish in same line even though I used `justify-content:"space-between"`
How can I achieve this like I want it to be seen?

Whats my mistake?

Here is the App.js, thanks for your help in advance

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Application from "./src/components/icons/application.svg"
import HorizontalCircles from './src/components/HorizontalCircles';
import HorizontalDiscussion from './src/components/HorizontalDiscussion';
import Energy from "./src/components/icons/energy.svg"
import Add from "./src/components/icons/add.svg"
import Calendar from "./src/components/icons/calendar.svg"
    
const App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.appIcon}>
        <Application height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
        <View style={{ height: 30, width: 30, backgroundColor: "#DBF1F9", borderRadius: 20 }} />
      </View>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="#B9B9C5"></TextInput>

      <View style={{ height: 100 }}>
        <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} contentContainerStyle={{ marginVertical: 20, alignItems: "center" }} horizontal={true}>
          <View style={{ height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", borderRadius: 20, marginRight: 10, borderStyle: "dotted", borderWidth: 5, borderColor: "#E2E2E2" }} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#CFC8FF"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#FFA2BF"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#FEE3AA"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#FEDFCC"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#FFA2BF"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#F3A5FF"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#EFBCFF"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#AFBFCF"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#AEDF5F"} />
          <HorizontalCircles color={"#DDB825"} />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

      <Text style={styles.blackText}>Group Discussion On Going</Text>

      <View style={{ height: 250 }}>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", }}>
          <HorizontalDiscussion color={"#FFF9F2"} />
          <HorizontalDiscussion color={"#E7FBFF"} />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

      <Text style={styles.blackText}>Todays Task</Text>

      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{padding:30}}>
          <View style={styles.task}>
            <View>
              <Energy height={35} width={25} fill={"#FB9238"} />


            </View>

            <View style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}>
              <Text style={styles.blackText}>8 Tasks Today</Text>
              <Text style={styles.grayText}>Meet them & Share your experience</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
              <Add height={35} width={25} fill={"#ABA8BA"} />

            </View>

          </View>

          <View style={styles.task}>
            <View >
              <Calendar height={35} width={25} fill={"#FCC626"} />

            </View>

            <View>
              <Text style={styles.blackText}>Event</Text>
              <Text style={styles.grayText}>Create & Share Event</Text>
            </View>

            <View>
              <Add height={35} width={25} fill={"#ABA8BA"} />

            </View>

          </View>


        </View>

      </ScrollView>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  },
  appIcon: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: .5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#F7F6F9",
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  blackText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
  },
  grayText: {
    color: "#A29E97",
    fontSize: 17,
  },
  task: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 15,
    justifyContent:"space-between"
  }


});

export default App;
```

this screen is after making flex:1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Dt0.png)

Comment: can you share this code on snack ?

Comment: but there are many icons... and  i deleted on my local, they are just on the project. I mean it would be so hard to add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code!! I mean adding the `flex:1`

```
                <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, flex: 1}}>
                  <Text style={styles.blackText}>8 Tasks Today</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>Meet them & Share your experience</Text>
                </View>
```

// other style

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "flex-start"}}>
              <Text style={styles.blackText}>Event</Text>
              <Text style={styles.grayText}>Create & Share Event</Text>
            </View>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Making flex:1 solved the + icon problem. they are now on the same line. But texts are still not. I added the pic in the question. Could u please look at my edit? how could i solve it

Comment: How you want your text, I cannot understand the image actually.

Comment: I want texts which are 8 Tasks Today and Event to start from same line.

Comment: I mean 8 Tasks Today should be the same distance from left, and Event text should be the same distance from left too

Comment: Use the same style for all the components.

Comment: They are the same tho, i didnt do any different for those both texts

Comment: I have updated the answer can you please check ?

Comment: Doing this ` {{ marginLeft: 15, flex: 1}}` for both worked, i just did this for one component before. Thank you a lot. But whats the difference? Why did only adding flex:1 solve this issue? could u tell a bit

Comment: You can refer this document, this will help you to understand the working of `flex` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean

Comment: Hello, can u look at this question please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803786/how-can-i-reach-the-variable-which-i-named-global-from-globalcontext