# How to create 3 divs side by side using flex where middle div can (grow&shrink) in respect to other two divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

How to create 3 divs side by side using flex where middle div can (grow&shrink) in respect to other two divs?

I want to create Three divs `A` `B` `C` with a parent containing `flex` css property. Having `A` fixed width of 300px and `C` having min width 200px and can grow in width as more content is added.

While `B` should be in between `A` and `C` should grow and shrink automatically as per the widths of `A` and `C`.

Although `A` and `C` can be of any width `300px` and `200px` are just examples.

I've tried but unable to place it correctly.

For `C` i used `flex: 1 1 0%;` with `A` and `C` with fixed width - **But didn't worked**

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code of your try - at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: more exemple : https://codepen.io/pk-salma/pen/qBjqwBG

Answer (score 1):

You can give `childB`, You can read more about [flex here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean)

```
flex: 1;
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.childA {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.childB {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.childC {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child childA">A</div>
  <div class="child childB">B</div>
  <div class="child childC">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be easier if you write your own code, which does not work

```css
.abc {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.A {
  min-width: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.B {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: grey;
}

.C {
  min-width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  width:25%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

you can use nth-child(**child**) to select any child and costom it

Result : https://codepen.io/pk-salma/pen/qBjqwBG