# Why are my flexbox items misaligned when the parent width changes?

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

I've got a problem with `flexbox`.
What I want to do is this:

[image: screenshot]

I almost did it.
However, for an unknown reason (for me), if the `width` (of the `div` or browser) is to small, it's not aligned anymore. The problem seems to be because of the multiple lorem ipsum, but I can't understand why.

[image]

```css
.timeline {
  display: flex;
}

.timeline>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.events {
  width: 50%;
}

.date,
.relative,
.events {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.date,
.relative {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="timeline">
    <p class="date">a1</p>
    <p class="relative">a2</p>
    <div>
      <div class="events"></div>
      <div class="events"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline">
    <p class="date">b1</p>
    <p class="relative">b2</p>
    <div>
      <div class="events">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="events">
        <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ium Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Do you have any idea what's going on? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Question modified!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex: 1;` instead of `flex-grow: 1;`.

`flex: 1;` is a shorthand for:

`flex-grow: 1;` = Element will grow in same proportion as the window-size

`flex-shrink: 1;` = Element will shrink in same proportion as the window-size

`flex-basis: 0;`  = Element does not have a starting value as such and will
take up screen as per the screen size available for e.g:- if 3 divs are in the wrapper then each div will take 33%.

**Source for above:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/37386525/14776809

```css
.timeline {
  display: flex;
}

.timeline>div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}

.events {
  width: 50%;
}

.date,
.relative,
.events {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.date,
.relative {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="timeline">
    <p class="date">a1</p>
    <p class="relative">a2</p>
    <div>
      <div class="events"></div>
      <div class="events"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline">
    <p class="date">b1</p>
    <p class="relative">b2</p>
    <div>
      <div class="events">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="events">
        <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ium Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```