# How to change height of an element according to its neighbors?

Tags: html, css

I have two text input boxes and a button in a row:

[image: css_error]

I want to make the height of the button same as text boxes.

This is the CSS code which I wrote:

```
.form-button {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
}

.form input[name="topText"] {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}

.form input[name="bottomText"] {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
return (
            <div>
                <form className="form">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="topText"
                        value={this.state.topText} 
                        placeholder="Top text"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="bottomText" 
                        value={this.state.bottomText} 
                        placeholder="Bottom text"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <button className="form-button">Gen</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
```

Even if I set the height of all the three elements as 30, the height of the button is not matching the text box.

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

Comment: Also share your `html` code.

Comment: I am using react js. So I have added that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `display: flex` to your form container and instead of putting the height on each input you could simply add height to the form element. `display: flex` will adjust the item's height automatically.

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
}

.form-button {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}

.form input[name="topText"] {
    width: 100px;
}

.form input[name="bottomText"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `<form .class="form"> </form>` is parent container give a height to it. Then make height of its children 100%

html code:

```
            <div>
            <form className="form">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="topText"
                    value={this.state.topText} 
                    placeholder="Top text"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="bottomText" 
                    value={this.state.bottomText} 
                    placeholder="Bottom text"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <button className="form-button">Gen</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

css code:

```
.form{
    height: 30px !important;
}
.form-button {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.form input[name="topText"] {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.form input[name="bottomText"] {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex;` along with `flex: 1;`.

`flex: 1;` is a shorthand for:

`flex-grow: 1;` The div will grow in same proportion as the window-size

`flex-shrink: 1;` The div will shrink in same proportion as the window-size

`flex-basis: 0;` The div does not have a starting value as such and will
take up screen as per the screen size available for
e.g:- if 3 divs are in the wrapper then each div will take 33%.

Source for above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37386525/14776809

This means all the child elements in the `form`'s height will be set to the child element with the biggest `height`-value, in this case the `input`-elements.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.form-button {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}

.form input[name="topText"] {
    width: 100px;
}

.form input[name="bottomText"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;`. This is what you wanted to do?

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/gOoqbBO

**HTML**

```
<form class="form">
  <input 
      type="text" 
      name="topText"
      value={this.state.topText} 
      placeholder="Top text"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
  <input 
      type="text" 
      name="bottomText" 
      value={this.state.bottomText} 
      placeholder="Bottom text"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
  <button class="form-button">Gen</button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100px;
}

.form-button {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}

.form input[name="topText"] {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100px;
}

.form input[name="bottomText"] {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi so I have a few comments to make about this bit of code you've shared, I hope it will help you to improve :)

1. ALWAYS `label` your `input` for accessibility purposes and visually hide it if you don't want it to be displayed (Beware /!\ Visually hiding an element ≠ `display:none`)

Here an article you can read on [w3c - Labeling Controls](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/) or [Web Aim - invisible content](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/)

2. As another user point it out, you can achieve what you're trying to do with Flex Layout here is [A Complete Guide to Flexbox on CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
3. There is also an unnecessary `<br />` in your code
4. in your`css`you also have 2 x color lines fir the same element.
5. both your inputs have the exact same code, always respect the **DRY** method (Don't Repeat Yourself) here is an old but efficient article about [7 Important Tips for Writing Better CSS on FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/7-important-tips-for-writing-better-css/)
6. Here you can see what I've achieved

```css
form{
  display:flex;
}

button {
  background-color: purple;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}

.sr-only{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
  <form>
    <label class="sr-only" for="topText">topText</label>
    <input type="text" name="topText" placeholder="topText">
    <label class="sr-only" for="bottomText">bottomText</label>
    <input type="text" name="bottomText" placeholder="bottomText">
    <button>Gen</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display:flex; and flex-wrap: wrap; to the parent class which is .form and avoid height css on inputs instead give paddings. Also avoid width unit in pixels instead add percentage and wrap it in a div which has width.

CSS

```
.form {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .form-button {
        background-color: purple;
        color: white;
        margin: 20px 0px;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        /* height: 30px; */ /*add padding instead of height*/
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      .form input[name="topText"] {
        margin: 20px 0px;
        width: 100px; /*avoid width in pixels instead add percentage % unit*/
        /* height: 30px; */ /*add padding instead of height*/
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      .form input[name="bottomText"] {
        margin: 20px 0px;
        width: 100px; /*avoid width in pixels instead add percentage % unit*/
        /* height: 30px; */ /*add padding instead of height*/
        padding: 1rem;
      }
```

JSX

```
    return (
<div>
          <form className="form">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="topText"
              value="{this.state.topText}"
              placeholder="Top text"
              onChange="{this.handleChange}"
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="bottomText"
              value="{this.state.bottomText}"
              placeholder="Bottom text"
              onChange="{this.handleChange}"
            />
            <br />
            <button className="form-button">Gen</button>
          </form>
        </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved without giving the form element a specific height and with 2 lines of css code only. Just give a `display: flex;` to `.form` and `.form-button` a `height: inherit;`.
(had to change 'className' to 'class' for html purpose in the snippet below)

```css
 .form-button {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: inherit
}

.form input[name="topText"] {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}

.form input[name="bottomText"] {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
.form {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <form class="form">
            <input 
                type="text" 
                name="topText"
                value={this.state.topText} 
                placeholder="Top text"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input 
                type="text" 
                name="bottomText" 
                value={this.state.bottomText} 
                placeholder="Bottom text"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br />
            <button class="form-button">Gen</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```