# how can i arrange pictures at div. like at the picture

Tags: html, css

I created a round div(border-radius: 50%) and want to flex my picture in triangular order
[image]

and what i need.

[image]

and thats my code.

```
<body bgcolor="gray">
<div align="center" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; background: white; border-radius: 50%; margin: auto; align-items: center; display: flex">
    <img src="../pics/tryceratops.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="border-radius: 50%;">
    <img src="../pics/stegozavr.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="border-radius: 50%;">
    <img src="../pics/tyranozavr.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="border-radius: 50%;">
</div>
```

yea i use style at tags cause it's homework

I don't want to bother with css files or style tags
but do as you like, I understand

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Each image must have its own class. and adjust using padding and margin. For example, for the image above, set the width to 100%  and set margin_left:25%;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `display: flex` because we don't need it here and add a `<br/>` tag after the first img, then adjust the `div` and `img` sizes so they properly fits.

I discovered a simple formula of `img_size * 2.3` to find the required height and width of `div` tag according to size of `img` tag

```
        <style>
            div {
                --s: 130px; /* Image size */
                --size: calc( var(--s) * 2.3 ); /* to calculate perfect div size acc. to image size */
                width: var(--size);
                height: var(--size);
                background: white;
                border-radius: 50%;
                margin: auto;
                background: #aaa;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px;

                transition: 2s;
            }

            img {
                width: var(--s);
                height: var(--s);
                border-radius: 50%;
            }

            div:hover {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        </style>

    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="pics/a.png" /><br />
            <img src="pics/b.png" />
            <img src="pics/c.png" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the preview...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <body bgcolor="gray">
    <div align="center" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: white; 
     border-radius: 50%; align-items: center;">
   <div>
    <img 
     src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MELeM.jpg" width="200" height="200" 
    style="border-radius: 50%;">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img 
 
     src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rt27.jpg" width="200" height="200" 
    style="border-radius: 50%;">
    <img
     src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvxqV.jpg" width="200" height="200" 
    style="border-radius: 50%;">
    </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `flex: 1` on your first child. I recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean) to understand what `flex: 1` does. I didn't try my code below, so you probably need to change something.

You can do it like this:

```
<img src="../pics/tryceratops.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="border-radius: 50%; flex: 1">
```

Edit: you probably need `flex-wrap` too.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes on html and css both file to achieved your expected result/output.

I hope you like it and learn something new from it.

```css
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {}

.second {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="gray">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="first">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvxqV.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="border-radius: 50%;">
    </div>

    <div class="second">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rt27.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="border-radius: 50%;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MELeM.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="border-radius: 50%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I made a snippet and removed the extra body tag

Comment: Thank you very much @mplungjan for your valuable edit. I am not familiar with stack overflow text editor.

Comment: Just click the `[<>]` button in the editor

Comment: your changes is showing run code snippet option but mine one is not showing.