# CSS image, object-fit: contain, margin: auto and percentage?

Tags: css

I'm looking for an alternative to this css code, which is working as expected on chrome, but not on firefox.

The pins are not keeping their position when the viewport size is different. You can resize (height and width) the viewport on jsfiddle on chrome to see what I expect and on firefox to see what I don't.
I guess there is something between margin: auto and object-fit: contain which is not calculated the same way...

[Chrome margin from devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REMgt.png)
[Firefox margin from devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHBj9.png)

I know that I can do it in javascript but i'd like to know if it's possible with css !

```
<div class="site">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="./img.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="pin-container">
        <div class="pin pin1">?</div>
        <div class="pin pin2">?</div>
        <div class="pin pin3">?</div>
        <div class="pin pin4">?</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.site{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-wrapper{
  height: 100%;
}

.img-wrapper img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.pin-container{
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pin{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pin1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 24%;
}
.pin2 {
  top: 30%;
  left: 52%;
}
.pin3 {
  top: 87%;
  left: 79%;
}
.pin4 {
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MathieuSP/8u3gLz4q/

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of `display: flex` in the `.wrapper`.

The [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) itself will always keep the content to fit inside so it will shrink your image down or scale it up.

You can use `flex: 1` to keep the image from being change (you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean)) and set the `aspect-ratio` to keep width and height of the image consistent. Just set it in the `.container`

```
 .container {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: auto;
    flex: 1;
    aspect-ratio: 1.5;
  }
```

Here is the snippet, hope this can help you

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.title{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.subtitle{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.site{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: auto;
    flex: 1;
    aspect-ratio: 1.5;
}

.img-wrapper{
  height: 100%;
}

.img-wrapper img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.pin-container{
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pin{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pin1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 24%;
}
.pin2 {
  top: 30%;
  left: 52%;
}
.pin3 {
  top: 87%;
  left: 79%;
}
.pin4 {
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">TITLE</div>
        <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1534057/pexels-photo-1534057.jpeg" alt="">

                <div class="pin-container">
                    <div class="pin pin1">?</div>
                    <div class="pin pin2">?</div>
                    <div class="pin pin3">?</div>
                    <div class="pin pin4">?</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was a great solution, but unfortunately, aspect-ratio can't be a dynamic value as far as I know. It works for the current test picture, but in my project they are not always the same ratio... The only way I see here is update the aspect-ratio value in javascript

Answer (score 0):

They are moving because their `container` **size** changes bigger than the `picture`. For such positioning, always put the `image` and `absolute elements` in one container with `fit-content width and height`. and of course `relative position` If you do so, they will stay in the same spot.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  .title{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  
  .subtitle{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  .site{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  
  .wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .container{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  .img-wrapper{
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .img-wrapper img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
  
  .pin-container{
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .pos-container {
    border: 3px solid orange;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  
  .pin{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .pin1 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 24%;
  }
  .pin2 {
    top: 30%;
    left: 52%;
  }
  .pin3 {
    top: 87%;
    left: 79%;
  }
  .pin4 {
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="site">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">TITLE</div>
        <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="pos-container">
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1534057/pexels-photo-1534057.jpeg" alt="">
                <div class="pin pin1">?</div>
                <div class="pin pin2">?</div>
                <div class="pin pin3">?</div>
                <div class="pin pin4">?</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: It's not working as expected. I'd like the picture to adapt its height to stay in the blue border div.

Comment: Do not resize the picture itself if you want to place elements on it. you can resize it by adjusting its container which is absolute elements container too. If you are interested, I can explain this concept to you in a separate answer. Good luck.