# Grid Row/Column settings

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, chakra-ui

I'm trying to create a Grid with React and Chakra-UI that behaves as follows:
[image: Grid behaviour]

Basically, depending on the amount of colors it is given (with a maximum of 6) it will automatically display them as shown.

The code so far is the following:

```
<Grid
  width={'20vw'}
  minWidth={'200px'}
  height={'20vh'}
  minHeight={'100px'}
  boxShadow={`${shadowColor} 0px 0px 2px`}
  // Grid settings here
>
  {simulationPalette.colors.map((color) => (
      <Box backgroundColor={color} />
  ))}
</Grid>
```

I tried some settings like

```
gridTemplateColumns={`repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50%, 1fr))`}
```

which would create empty space in case of an odd number of colors

or simply

```
gridTemplateColumns={auto-fill}
```

which would just use a new columns for ever color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need flexbox:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container div {
  /* Make them as wide as possible from a basis of 0 and shrink as needed */
  /* (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/37386244 for more information) */
  flex: 1;
  /* ...but not narrower than 1 / 3 of the container. */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

You also need to add a class or similar to let CSS know if `#container` has more than 4 children:

```css
#container.more-than-4-colors div {
  min-width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```js
const method = container.children.length > 4 ? 'add' : 'remove';
container.classList[method]('more-than-4-colors');
```

When the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class gets widely supported, you can use this:

```css
/* Not yet widely supported */
#container:has(> :nth-child(5)) div {
  min-width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Try it:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');

  if (container.children.length === 6) {
    container.innerHTML = '';
  }
  
  container.appendChild(element);
  
  const method = container.children.length > 4 ? 'add' : 'remove';
  container.classList[method]('more-than-4-colors');
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container div {
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: calc(100% / 2);
}

#container.more-than-4-colors div {
  min-width: calc(100% / 3);
}

/* Not yet widely supported */
#container:has(> :nth-child(5)) {
  min-width: calc(100% / 3);
}


/* Demo only */

#container {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

#container div {
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid var(--border);
  background: var(--background);
}

#container div:nth-child(1) {
  --border: #6c8ebf;
  --background: #dae8fc;
}

#container div:nth-child(2) {
  --border: #82b366;
  --background: #d5e8d4;
}

#container div:nth-child(3) {
  --border: #9673a6;
  --background: #e1d5e7;
}

#container div:nth-child(4) {
  --border: #d79b00;
  --background: #ffe6cc;
}

#container div:nth-child(5) {
  --border: #b85450;
  --background: #f8cecc;
}

#container div:nth-child(6) {
  --border: #d6b656;
  --background: #fff2cc;
}
```

```html
<button>Add</button>

<div id="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It generally works, but not with the case of 4 colors, in which there should be 2 colors above and 2 below

Comment: @HeavenlyJourney Fixed. See if it works.