# Why is flex-basis: 0 needed for scrollable flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created this snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px
}

.modal {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.box {
  height: 300px;
}

.box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <span>heading</span>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="box box-yellow"></div>
        <div class="box box-blue"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to create a modal with a header, scrollable content and a footer.

The order of the markup is required as is.

My question is why does it have to be:

```
.content {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Why can't it just be:

```
.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The final goal is achieved but as a beginner in flexbox, I would like to know why `flex: 1 1 0px` is needed.

I have read some documentation about flex-basis, but it looks like flex-basis has several behaviors. What is going in this specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a little tricky; it is a bit [buried in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#change-2012-flex-basis-zero), but the default flex basis (when omitted in a `flex` declaration) is `0%`.

For your case, `0%` means nothing, because the parent doesn't have a specified height (similarly, `height: 0%` wouldn't mean anything). This causes it to be ignored, and it falls back to `auto`, which ends up expanding the whole thing.

Setting it to `0px` on the other hand works, because it can properly be resolved and so actually takes effect.

### Edit

I suppose I should elaborate a bit more here. The way flexbox works, is that it takes the flex items, and after laying them out in your flexbox, it distributes or removes any positive or negative space based on the defined `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` properties.

Now, with that in mind, there are actually two relevant flexboxes at play here; `.container` and `.content`. Note that the `.container` is not a scroll container, whereas `.content` is.

Another relevant fact is `min-height`; its default is `auto`. In the context of a flex item, this means it computes to `min-content` if the container is not a scroll container, and `0` otherwise ([see this bit in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)).

Now, let's put these together. The `.content` element, if it has a `flex-basis` of `0%`, ends up falling back to `auto`. It wants to be a scroll container, but its parent, `.container`, doesn't, and has no height specified; that means the parent will just overflow, and the `.content` element ends up not flexing, since it has no desired height. It doesn't become a scroll container at all.

One way of solving this, instead of setting `flex: 1 1 0px` on `.content`, is by setting `height: 0;` or `min-height: 0;` on the `.container`. That way, the overflowing has to be done in the `.content` element, resulting in the wanted behavior.

If you instead use `flex: 1 1 0px`, then the `.content` will, before flexing, be laid out as having a height of `0px`; this will not trigger overflow on the parent. After this, flexing will be applied and the element grows to fit its parent container (without overflowing). In this case, `.content` becomes a scroll container.

Comment: Thank you, I understand why the default value doesn't work. What about the "0px"? The documentation says that flex-basis "sets the size of the content box", doesn't "0px" means nothing too?

Comment: `0px` is an absolute value, it always means something. Having a `flex-basis` of `0px` causes the browser to consider the element as having a height of `0px`, after which it'll apply the flexing. Since it also has `flex-grow: 1`, it ends up growing to fill the remaining space.

Comment: amazing, `height: 0` on the `.container` works too, what I learn from this is that the height will be set first, then the flex will take place, I'm accepting this answer, please fix the link in the edit, thanks for the help!

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out - link should be fixed now. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

`flex: 1` is equivalent to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto`

With `flex-basis: auto` (content-based length), the container will simply shrink and expand to accommodate the height or width of the content. There is no limit that would trigger a scrollbar.

With `flex-basis: 0px`, you are setting a defined length, which is enough to trigger a scrollbar (in conjunction with `flex-grow: 1`, in this case).

By the way, you don't even need to define the `px` units. `flex-basis: 0` is enough.

But don't use percentage units (`%`), as that would cause the scrollbar to fail, as you would need to define lengths on parent containers.

Comment: Nope.`flex: 1` is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 0%` in all browsers. The `<positive-number>` stuff at https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common, which says `flex-basis:0` is wrong.

Comment: Sorry my friend, the authority is the spec, which says `flex: 1` is `flex: 1 1 0`. Browser makers can do whatever they want. If they deviate from the spec, that doesn't make them right. It makes them wrong. But again, they can do whatever they want. @dgrogan

Comment: You do realize your answer is wrong either way, right?

Comment: How so?   @dgrogan

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting, the spec says: "flex: <positive-number> is equivalent to flex: <positive-number> 1 0", why do you say the default value (for flex-basis) is "auto"? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamírez, because when the `flex` property isn't defined, `flex-basis` is `auto` by default.

Comment: hi, thank you for following up, this answer states that `flex: 1` is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 0`, not to `flex: 1 1 auto` https://stackoverflow.com/a/37386525/16703278 could you clarify please?

Comment: I'm not sure what part is unclear. As I stated earlier, when the `flex` property is not used, `flex-basis` is `auto` by default. [That's its initial value.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property). When the `flex` property is used, and is defined with a single integer, `flex-basis` defaults to 0 (as you noted in your comment above). @JoseCarlosRamírez

Comment: hi, I'm a little bit confused, check these two snippets: https://jsfiddle.net/cexa946j/1/ https://jsfiddle.net/cexa946j/2/ one has `flex: 1` and the other one has `flex: 1 1 0`, however they don't behave the same? Isn't `flex: 1` supposed to be equal to `flex: 1 1 0`?

Comment: Yes, `flex: 1` is supposed to be equal to `flex: 1 1 0`. That is correct and valid. Both snippets should render the same. But, as I mentioned in my first comment, browser makers can do whatever they want. They are not obligated to follow spec rules. In this case, Chrome deviates from the spec by rendering `flex: 1` as `flex: 1 1 0%` (see DevTools). By adding the percentage unit, the layout fails, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Oh, wow! I had not idea Chrome did that. It's good to be aware of this. Thank you a lot for your answer, it was really helpful :)